# How to import BCH address into Exodus wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, private-key-import, exodus

How do I link my Bitcoin private key to my new Exodus BCH wallet so that I can claim my BCH?!

Can't find anything on here. Can't find anything on the Exodus website. Can't find anything on Google or Youtube...

I've got my Bitcoin address private key, but I simply need to associate it with my Exodus BCH wallet somehow to claim my BCH.

I'm baffled there isn't any information out there on how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: You can help the site by marking answers as accepted if they are correct and address the question. If none of the answers helps then you can by writing up the solution as an answer (since you have it sorted) and marking it as accepted so that the question does not remain as "unanswered".

Comment: @Willtech i know how it works ;) JP's response isn't sufficient to be marked as an answer, however

Answer (score 1):

Exodus co-founder here...

Take your Bitcoin private key, and move the funds via the Bitcoin Cash private key import/move. Note, this moves the Bitcoin Cash only from the private key into Exodus. Here's how this can be done: http://support.exodus.io/article/87-can-i-import-a-private-key

Note, you'll select `Bitcoin Cash`, unlike the article which shows Bitcoin.

Comment: i'm getting an error message that states "invalid network version" what to do?! you're sure i should be importing via 'Bitcoin Cash' and not 'Bitcoin'? whomever is in charge of email support made absolutely zero mention of this

Comment: notably, i'm trying to link the private key of my Bitcoin Core wallet so that i can claim my BCH. somebody edited my question and bastardized it

Comment: @Anthony the edits look accurate in English. Your Bitcoin Core wallet holds a private key for Bitcoin which is what you want to import into Exodus to claim your BCH, right?

Comment: @Anthony Anyway, I just gave it a quick try in Exodus and it seems to work fine. Are you using the most recent version of Exodus?

Comment: @Willtech i talked to somebody via email support and they walked me thru it.